# Only displaying part of a div loaded by AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I'm using the [cross-domain-ajax](https://github.com/padolsey-archive/jquery.fn/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax) jQuery plug in to load some offsite content into my page.

The div I am loading looks like this on the original source site :

```
 <div class="trkp-hdr-img"><a href="/title/501166/cause-your-lies-ep"><img src="http://geo.static.traxsource.com/files/images/478052.jpg" /></a></div>
```

And the way I am loading it is like this :

```
 $.ajax({
url: 'http://www.traxsource.com/track/2655665/cause-your-lies',
type: 'GET',
success: function(res) {
    var artwork = $(res.responseText).find('.trkp-hdr-img').html();
    $('.mydiv').html(artwork);
}
});
```

This works, but I'd like to know if it's possible to only return the img src part of this div, so it just displays the link to the image.

I know if the image had been in it's own div this would be simple, but as it's wrapped in an  tag it's not possible.

Is there any jQuery magic that can find this div and then filter out everything except the img tag?

Comment: did you try only looking up the image? as in `$(res.responseText).find('.trkp-hdr-img img');`

Comment: Yep tired that, returns nothing :(

Comment: really? any console errors? - did you try exactly as I mentioned (without `.html()` at the end)

Comment: Ahh weirdly enough though, $(res.responseText).find('.trkp-hdr-img a'); does return only the img tags :)

Comment: Yes, it will return anything else inside the `a` tag as well (not just the `img` one) - that's why I am wondering about the `img` tag without using `.html()` at the end... it should work

Comment: Yes you are correct, it does work without the .html() at the end. I missed that ;)

Comment: Is there anyway to append a custom width and height to the returned img tags too?

Comment: Sure, see my updated answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this line:

`var artwork = $(res.responseText).find('.trkp-hdr-img').html();`

for this one:

`var artwork = $(res.responseText).find('.trkp-hdr-img img');`

It should return an object with the `img` element itself.

**UPDATED (from comments)**

If you wanted to add custom height and width attributes, add this line after the one above.

```
// dimensions are in pixels (in this case (200x200)
$(artwork).attr('width', 200).attr('height', 200);
```

Comment: Absolute legend! Thank you so much @ochi